# Removing line breaks when writing to txt file

Tags: python, user-controls, match

When the 'user input' matches a word in document "Updated_Word.doc", the string plus the following two lines will be written on a separate txt file called word_file.txt. The problem that I'm having is when I open the txt file it looks like this:

```
Match Word

Line 1
    
Line 2
```

I know this may be a simple solution but I'm struggling to figure out a way to write those lines to a txt file without the line breaks. Example:

```
Match Word
Line 1
Line 2
```

Here's the part of the code that executes the match and writing to the txt file:

```py
def grabWord():
string = input('Input Word Name:\n')
user_input = re.compile(string)
x = user_input.findall('Updated_Word.doc')
    with open('Updated_Word.doc', mode='r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if string in line:
            print('Found Match!')
            with open('Word_file.txt', mode='a') as outfile:
                if line.strip():
                    x = [line, next(infile), next(infile), next(infile), next(infile)]
                    outfile.writelines(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are writing the line found plus the next 4 lines, and two of them are just line breaks.

```
if line.strip():
    x = [line, next(infile), next(infile), next(infile), next(infile)]
```

a quick & dirty fix would be to filter your final result removing those otherwise empty lines:

```
if line.strip():
    x = [line, next(infile), next(infile), next(infile), next(infile)]
    x = (list(filter(lambda element: element.strip(), x)))
    outfile.writelines(x)
```

another way is to search for the next two non-empty lines:

```
if line.strip():
    two_next_lines = []

    try:
        while len(two_next_lines) < 2:
            current = next(line)

            if current.strip():
                two_next_lines.append(current)
    except StopIteration:
        # there are not enough next lines matching your requirements
        pass


    x = [line] + [two_next_lines]
    outfile.writelines(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.